# Reading a Binary File that was generated with C++ data types Using Numpy

Tags: python, c++, numpy, binaryfiles

I am attempting to read a binary file with a known data type that was generated in C++ with the following structure:

```
    uint64_t shot;
    uint32_t status;
    double easting, northing, altitude;
    uint32_t  zoneNumber;

    char zoneLetter;

    float vNorth, vEast, vDown;
    float qw, qx, qy, qz;
    float acel_x, acel_y, acel_z, gyro_x, gyro_y, gyro_z;

    float rollStdDev, pitchStdDev, yawStdDev;
    float northingStdDev, eastingStdDev, altitudeStdDev;
    float vNorthStdDev, vEastStdDev, vDownStdDev;
```

The only strangeness happening here is that the 'zoneletter' is a 1byte character with 3 bytes of padding following. So the character should start on byte 40 and then vNorth should start on byte 44.

This is my attempting at reading this binary file with python using numpy. I am unsure about if I converted the c++ doubles correctly, and I am pretty sure my problems are coming from reading the character.

The problem being that on the first iteration shot and status are reading correctly, but thereafter everything that is reading doesn't make any sense to what the actual data should look like. So I believe there is a problem with either the character or double reading from bytes 12-44.

```
dt2 = np.dtype([('ShotNum', np.uint64), ('Status', np.uint32), ('easting', np.float_),\
            ('northing', np.float_),('alt', np.float_), ('Znum', np.uint32),('letter', np.character),\
            ('vnorth', np.float32),('veast', np.float32),('vdown', np.float32),\
            ('qw', np.float32),('qx', np.float32),('qy', np.float32),('qz', np.float32),\
            ('acX', np.float32),('acY',np.float32),('acZ', np.float32),('gyX', np.float32),\
            ('gyY', np.float32),('gyZ', np.float32),('rollSTD', np.float32),('pitSTD', np.float32),\
            ('yawSTD', np.float32),('northSTD', np.float32),('eastSTD', np.float32),('altSTD', np.float32),\
            ('vnorthSTD', np.float32),('veastSTD', np.float32),('vDownSTD', np.float32)])
```

Here is the c++ explicit struct

```
[thread: 892] mainwindow.cpp(65): Sizeof NavigationSolution:  136  bytes
[thread: 892] mainwindow.cpp(66): shot
[thread: 892] mainwindow.cpp(67):    bytes:  8
[thread: 892] mainwindow.cpp(68):   offset:  0
[thread: 892] mainwindow.cpp(69): status
[thread: 892] mainwindow.cpp(70):    bytes:  4
[thread: 892] mainwindow.cpp(71):   offset:  8
[thread: 892] mainwindow.cpp(72): easting
[thread: 892] mainwindow.cpp(73):    bytes:  8
[thread: 892] mainwindow.cpp(74):   offset:  16
[thread: 892] mainwindow.cpp(75): northing
[thread: 892] mainwindow.cpp(76):    bytes:  8
[thread: 892] mainwindow.cpp(77):   offset:  24
[thread: 892] mainwindow.cpp(78): altitude
[thread: 892] mainwindow.cpp(79):    bytes:  8
[thread: 892] mainwindow.cpp(80):   offset:  32
[thread: 892] mainwindow.cpp(81): zoneNumber
[thread: 892] mainwindow.cpp(82):    bytes:  4
[thread: 892] mainwindow.cpp(83):   offset:  40
[thread: 892] mainwindow.cpp(84): zoneLetter
[thread: 892] mainwindow.cpp(85):    bytes:  1
[thread: 892] mainwindow.cpp(86):   offset:  44
[thread: 892] mainwindow.cpp(87): vNorth
[thread: 892] mainwindow.cpp(88):    bytes:  4
[thread: 892] mainwindow.cpp(89):   offset:  48
[thread: 892] mainwindow.cpp(90): vEast
[thread: 892] mainwindow.cpp(91):    bytes:  4
[thread: 892] mainwindow.cpp(92):   offset:  52
[thread: 892] mainwindow.cpp(93): vDown
[thread: 892] mainwindow.cpp(94):    bytes:  4
[thread: 892] mainwindow.cpp(95):   offset:  56
```

…etc

Comment: *"I am pretty sure my problems ..."*  You haven't explained your problems.  That makes it difficult to help you solve them. :)

Comment: I don't think `('letter', np.character)` will work.  You need to account for all four bytes (letter and padding).  Try replacing that with `('letter', 'S1'), ('padding', 'S3')`.

Comment: edited problem for a little more clarity. Ill give it a shot Warren

Comment: I tried your solution Warren, and the output still doesn't make sense. I am unsure if a C++ double is a python numpy float_

Comment: `np.float_` is the same as `np.float64`.  I don't have experience with a lot of compilers, but I'm pretty sure all the major modern compilers use IEEE 754 double precision floating point for a C `double`.

Comment: Exactly how was the binary file created?  Are the C++ variables that you show actually the fields in a `struct`, and was that `struct` written out as a single block of memory?  Or is each field written separately?  If the former, be aware that the compiler may add padding to the struct (perhaps to improve memory alignment).  For example, the compiler might have added four bytes after the `status` field to give `easting` an eight-byte alignment.

Comment: I updated with another block of code that shows the cpp struct explicitly

Comment: Great, that helps a lot.  Note that the offset of `easting` is 16, not 12.

Comment: Warren, this is something I completely overlooked. Would you like to create an answer to the question so I can accept it? I added in 4bytes of padding after status and everything works now!

Comment: @IanCampbellMoore -- This is why you must define your file layout **before** doing anything else.  Right now you're gambling that things line up right in the file, instead of enforcing (through good documentation) *how* fields are supposed to layed out in the file.  If you get any good file layout description, the description tells you that bytes 1 - 4 are this, bytes 5 - 10 are that, etc.  Then the language that implements reading and writing that file must follow the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to account for the padding that the compiler adds to the `struct`.  For example, the offset of `easting` is 16 bytes, not 12.  The compiler added four bytes of padding, presumably to give `easting` an eight-byte alignment.

If this work is part of a long-term project, think twice about using this format.  It is compiler-dependent.  If the C++ code that generates the binary file is compiled with a different compiler (or perhaps even with same compiler but different compiler options), the padding in the binary file could change, and the Python code would not read the file correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Warren Weckesser pointed out that your problems stemmed from missing padding in your NumPy dtype.  While it's true that you can fix it manually by adding explicit pad fields, you can also fix it automatically with the `align=True` option to [`np.dtype`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.html):

> align : **bool, optional**
>
> Add padding to the fields to match what a C
>   compiler would output for a similar C-struct.

Also, you might consider representing your structure in NumPy with nested arrays, for example instead of this:

```
('qw', np.float32),('qx', np.float32),('qy', np.float32),('qz', np.float32)
```

You could do:

```
('q', np.float32, 4)
```

Then any value in `arr.q` will be an array of length 4, which depending on your application may be easier to deal with.

Comment: Great tip!  Is there a C/C++ standard for padding the fields of a struct?  Or does it just happen to work out that the popular C/C++ compilers all do the same thing?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser: It is implementation-defined.  However, if OP is happy with the implementation-defined nature of his C++ structs, he may be satisfied with the same in Python.  If OP wants to be cross-platform, the solution is the opposite: `align=False` (the default) in NumPy, and compiler-specific pragmas to enable structure packing in C++.  Then, add explicit padding back in if required.

Comment: As an example, `double easting` would have no padding before it on 32-bit x86 (we can surmise OP is using a 64-bit system).